# Adding one variable to another variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm a student and struggling to get my javascript to add the VAT to the other 'variable'

can somebody please assist - the vat displays as "0"

```
function calculateTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  var vat = total*0.14;

  for (var k = 0; k < document.forms.service.length; k++)
  {    
    if(document.forms.service.elements[k].checked){
      total+=Number(document.forms.service.elements[k].value);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "The total is R " + total;
  document.getElementById("vat").innerHTML= "The total VAT is R " + vat;
}
```

Comment: `0*0.14` is always `0`

Comment: Anything multiplied by 0 will be 0...so the lines `var total = 0; total * 0.14` may be a bit useless :D

Comment: Move this `var vat = total*0.14;` after `for` loop

Comment: Wonder why someone downvoted the question. It lists the code, it's clear what's expected and the OP explained what actually happened. Just because it's a simple error, doesn't make it a bad question

Comment: Why was this put on hold? It was not a typographical error, it was a logic error.

Answer (score 4):

Move `var vat = total*0.14;` to the end of the function. You have to calculate the vat after you calculate the total.

```
function calculateTotal(){
  var total = 0;

  for (var k = 0; k < document.forms.service.length; k++)
  {    
    if(document.forms.service.elements[k].checked){
      total+=Number(document.forms.service.elements[k].value);
    }
  }

  var vat = total*0.14;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "The total is R " + total;
  document.getElementById("vat").innerHTML= "The total VAT is R " + vat;
}
```